# Imagem vertical tirada no smartphone "fica" horizontal ao fazer upload

Tags: php, jcrop

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu cheguei aqui depois de procurar entender e procurar alguma solução, mas esta é uma das raras vezes que posso dizer que não tenho a menor ideia do que fazer.
É um pequeno sistema de imobiliárias (a imagem é de um lavabo).
A foto foi tirada de um smartphone e está normal no computador (de pé).
Ao clicar para fazer o upload, ela fica horizontal (neste caso estou usando o Jcrop para fazer o upload).

Teria algum início de ideia do que pode ser que ocasione isso?

Comment: Coloque o código de renderização da imagem.